# How come a proc local variable interferes with global variable

Tags: tcl

I am using TCL 8.6.

Here is the code:

```
proc unpack_list {list1  list2} {
    set i 0
    foreach e $list2 {
        puts "globals=[info globals $e]"
        global $e
        set $e [lindex $list1 $i] 
        incr i
    }
}

set l1 [list 10 20 30 40]
set l2 [list a b c e]
unpack_list $l1 $l2
puts $a
puts $b
puts $c
puts $e
puts [info globals ]
```

Running the code fails:

```
globals=
globals=
globals=
globals=
variable "e" already exists
    while executing
"global $e"
    (procedure "unpack_list" line 5)
    invoked from within
"unpack_list $l1 $l2"
    (file "tmp/1.tcl" line 13)
```

The problem lies at this line:

```
set l2 [list a b c e]
```

If I change "e" to "ee", the script runs fine:

```
globals=
globals=
globals=
globals=
10
20
30
40
tcl_rcFileName tcl_version argv0 argv tcl_interactive a ee b c auto_path env tcl_pkgPath tcl_patchLevel l1 argc l2 tcl_library tcl_platform
```

My question is: The variable "e" inside the proc does not exist in global namespace, how come it interferes with the global variable "e"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you seem to want, you can use the `upvar` command. Try this version of the unpack_list command:

```
proc unpack_list {list1 list2} {
    foreach v $list1 e $list2 {
        upvar #0 $e var
        set var $v
    }
}
```

This will never cause a clash between the global and local variable names.

Comment: This is how to fix the problem, but not what is actually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the description of the `global` command it states that the command creates a local variable that is linked to a global variable. The error message tells the story. The local variable already exists and `global` refuses to change its reference. To do otherwise would make local variables change values magically.

Comment: This is what the problem is, but not how to fix it.

Comment: Admittedly, a very narrow answer, but the question was about why the error occurred, not how to code the dubious undertaking of pushing values into global variables.